# Call expect file from C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, expect, ubuntu-12.04

I coded a **ftp.exp** file which sends a log file of a C application to a server.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
spawn ftp xxx.xxx.xxx 21
match_max 100000
expect -re {[2]{2,}[0]{1,}}
send -- "usrxxxx"
expect -exact "usrxxxxx"
send -- "\r"
expect -re {[3]{2,}[1]{1,}}
send -- "xxxx\r"
expect -exact "\r
230 Access granted for xxxxxxxxxx !\r
Remote system type is UNIX.\r
Using binary mode to transfer files.\r
ftp> "
send -- "put /home/User/test.txt test2.txt\r"
expect -exact "put /home/User/test.txt test2.txt\r"
send -- "\r"
expect -re {[2]{2,}[6]{1,}}
send -- "quit\r"
expect eof
```

The script works fine but how can I execute the file from a **C Application**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [system(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) or [popen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) library functions to run your expect script from your C code. These functions are using [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) like [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) which you could also use by yourself.

I strongly suggest learning more about [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [advanced linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/); there are some concepts and tricks to learn.

I believe you'll better use `ssh` (with `scp`) than an expect script sending plain passwords on the wire to a distant remote FTP server (there are some security issues with your approach).

Comment: I know of the ftp security problem... but the server is just a test server... thks anyway....

Comment: You could use the `syslog(3)` library function and configure appropriately your syslog service (e.g. your `syslogd`) to send remotely some logs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [libexpect](http://cims.nyu.edu/cgi-systems/man.cgi?section=3&topic=libexpect) and call your script from its api.

I found only the php bindings for it, but I have no Debian here to tell you what package provides the base package.