# stdout to a variable c/c++

Tags: c++, c, linux, system, stdout

I am using `int res = system("uname -p");` in my c++ code.

It will give the the result in standard output by using

`fprintf(stdout,"execution returned %d.\n",res);`

I want to store this result string in a variable, I am unable to store it.

I google it but unable to find proper solution, Can any one tell me the correct way.

Comment: What you want to store in string varbiale - res or what?

Comment: I think he wants to store the output of running `uname -p` in a string variable.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear. I run `uname -p` in a terminal on my computer, and it outputs `i386`. You want to end up with a string variable that contains `i386`, right? If so, you'll need [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) and read from the stream it returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125828/capturing-stdout-from-a-system-command-optimally

Comment: @millimoose yes i want to store the i386 in a string so that i can use it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need to run the `uname` command programmatically to get your processor. You can simply run the [uname(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/uname.2.html) [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (which the `uname` command invokes). And you could also read and parse `/proc/cpuinfo` from your program.

If you wanted to read the output of some command, use [popen(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) library function.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12331321/841108) to a related question.

Comment: hey thanks millimoose & BasileStarynkevitch the popen() works for me Great !!! :)

Comment: But in your case you really should use `uname(2)`; doing a `popen` is ridiculous for that